# How to remove a group of specific rows from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 7581 rows and 3 columns (id,text,label). And I have a subgroup of this dataframe of 794 rows.

What I need to do is to remove that subgroup of 794 rows (same labels) from the big dataframe of 7581.

This is how the subgroup looks like:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cocCu.png)

I have tried to do this:

```
final = trainData_Ceros.drop(rus1,axis=0)
```

But the following error appears:

```
KeyError: "['id' 'text' 'label'] not found in axis"
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: drop needs either column or index to drop. So you have to provide the index of the rows in which id is in this variable rus1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this slicing

```
final[~final.id.isin(rus1)]
```

And if you want to use drop then you can do this

```
final.drop(final[final.id.isin(rus1)].index)
```

Comment: Hi! The problem is that, every label of the big group is 0, that doesn't work. I need to filter it by the column 'id', but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I thought you meant by label. If you have the id values in this rus1 variable then the edited answer should work

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to add to your answer the following: trainData_Ceros[~trainData_Ceros.id.isin(rus1['id'])] .  The column 'id'. Now it works